# Substracting a string column

Tags: python, pandas

if I had this data frame:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['I\'m','I\'m','I\'m'],
                          'B':['From Spain','From Italy','From France'],
                          'C':['I\'m John From Spain, I\'m 10 Years Old','I\'m Josh From Italy, I\'m 11 Years Old','I\'m Jan From France, I\'m 12 Years Old']})

     A            B                                      C
0  I'm   From Spain  I'm John From Spain, I'm 10 Years Old
1  I'm   From Italy  I'm Josh From Italy, I'm 11 Years Old
2  I'm  From France  I'm Jan From France, I'm 12 Years Old
```

i want a column 'D' that Substracts A and B From C and returns a result like this:

```
     A            B                                      C     D
0  I'm   From Spain  I'm John From Spain, I'm 10 Years Old  John
1  I'm   From Italy  I'm Josh From Italy, I'm 11 Years Old  Josh
2  I'm  From France  I'm Jan From France, I'm 12 Years Old   Jan
```

How can I Do that?

UPDATE: I just need the value between A and B and ignore everything else

Comment: What about `I'm 10 Years Old` etc.?

Comment: no i don't need it

Comment: Care to explain the logic on why that isn't included in `D`?

Comment: i just need the value between A and B and ignore everything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

def search(x):
    m = re.search(r'{}\s*(.*?)\s*{}'.format(re.escape(x.A), re.escape(x.B)), x.C)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return x.C

dataframe1['D'] = dataframe1.apply(search, axis=1)
print(dataframe1)
```

Prints:

```
     A            B                                      C     D
0  I'm   From Spain  I'm John From Spain, I'm 10 Years Old  John
1  I'm   From Italy  I'm Josh From Italy, I'm 11 Years Old  Josh
2  I'm  From France  I'm Jan From France, I'm 12 Years Old   Jan
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s= dataframe1['A'].unique().tolist() + (dataframe1['B'].unique() + '.*$').tolist()
regstr = '|'.join(s)

dataframe1['D'] = dataframe1['C'].str.replace(regstr, '')
dataframe1
```

Output:

```
     A            B                                      C       D
0  I'm   From Spain  I'm John From Spain, I'm 10 Years Old   John 
1  I'm   From Italy  I'm Josh From Italy, I'm 11 Years Old   Josh 
2  I'm  From France  I'm Jan From France, I'm 12 Years Old    Jan
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that name lies in second place you can try this

```
    dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['I\'m','I\'m','I\'m'],
                      'B':['From Spain','From Italy','From France'],
                      'C':['I\'m John From Spain, I\'m 10 Years Old','I\'m Josh From Italy, I\'m 11 Years Old','I\'m Jan From France, I\'m 12 Years Old']})

    dataframe1["D"]=dataframe1.apply(lambda x: x.C.split()[1],axis=1)
    dataframe1
```

output:

```
        A   B   C                                                   D
    0   I'm     From Spain  I'm John From Spain, I'm 10 Years Old   John
    1   I'm     From Italy  I'm Josh From Italy, I'm 11 Years Old   Josh
    2   I'm     From France     I'm Jan From France, I'm 12 Years Old   Jan
```